# Is the Dragon Ball Super manga "more faithful" to Akira Toriyama ideas than the anime?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-manga

After hearing some dragon ball youtubers I remember one of them told that Akira Toriyama gives a bullet list of ideas he wants the anime and the manga artist Toyotaro to follow and then they have some freedom to develop the story, this is why we see differences in techniques, events, the order the characters are eliminated in the tournament of power, and by whom etc. But then, another youtuber, a spanish speaking one with 1,3 million followers said that aside of giving the primary ideas of the story, Akira gives some sort of supervision in the manga. Is this so? Is the Dragon Ball Super manga "more faithful" to Akira Toriyama ideas than the anime?

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. Toriyama has a lot of control with regard to the anime. An article [here](http://comicbook.com/anime/2017/11/10/dragon-ball-super-akira-toriyama-involvement-toei-changes/) indicates, how 2 Dragon Ball Super executives reveal at an anime convention, as to how much control they have over Toriyama.  The staff often build upon his ideas. You can always read his original drafts for every arc and see that the majority of the story is built on his ideas and that staff often work around his main plot and add characters. Here is Toriyama's original draft of the [*"Tournament of Power arc"*](https://twitter.com/Herms98/status/972038504992587776)

Some interesting points:

- If you look at the preview of the Tournament of Power exhibition match, the character in the hood was initially supposed to be Jiren and not Toppo. However, Toriyama mentioned Jiren's backstory and said he was a character who didn't speak and then originated Toppo's character.
- When the Dragon Ball Super staff considered Broly's popularity and presented Kale's idea to Toriyama, he added Caulifla.
- Even the Ultra Instinct transformation was completely decided by Toriyama and he came up with the Perfected Ultra Instinct idea. So the idea of Ultra Instinct Omen Goku might very well have been Toei's to probably create hype for the special and keep the audience interested.

With regard to the manga, Toyataro is ultimately forced to follow the main plot line of Toriyama's original draft. However, at the same time, Toyotaro definitely has the freedom to incorporate his own ideas and deviate from the script.
In a discussion between Toyotaro and Toriyama with regard to the [*"Future Trunks arc"*](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/translations/dragon-ball-super-tori-toyo-free-talk-vol-2/), it was outright stated that the differences we see in the manga and anime; one good example of the same is Vegeta using Super Saiyan God, are Toyotaros ideas. Toriyama  himself encourages Toyataro to incorporate his own ideas into the main plot.

Akira Toriyama indeed supervises the manga. However, his supervision is mainly with regard to the main plot line and certain differences we see in the manga are mainly Toyotaro's ideas which Toriyama accepts (Like the Super Saiyan God Vegeta).